# Display image in img tag stored as BLOB in database

Tags: java, blob, java-web-start

I can't display `BLOB` image that I have in `mysql` saved. I have beans, jsp. I use 3multy-tier architecture, I want to display all the products with the picture.

**In acceesor:**

```
 try {
        Connection cn = getVla().getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<products> ls = new ArrayList<products>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            products s = new products();
            s.setPk(rs.getLong("pk"));
            s.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            s.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
            s.setPic(rs.getBlob("pic"));
            s.setComments(rs.getString("comments"));
            ls.add(s);
        }
        return ls;
    }
```

**In products:**

```
 public Blob getPic() {
        return pic;
    }
```

**In main.jsp**

```
<%=
List<products> product = bean.getproducts();

%>
<h1>Product: </h1>
<%  
for(products c : product) { 
%>
From <%= c.getName()%> <br/>
<%= c.getPic()%></b><br/>
<b><%= c.getPrice()%> </b><br/>
<%= c.getComments()%>
<hr/>
<%
}
%>
```

How I can display the picture? (Currently I am getting com.mysql.jdbc.Blob@2e5f6a64 in display)

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to display **one** picture per product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is the result of `Blob.toString()`. Since it's binary content, the JVM cannot really figure a nice representation.

What you should do is create a seperate Servlet that only retrieves the `Blob` from the database and streams its content to `response.getOutputStream()`. In your JSP, you add an `<img>` tag whose `src`-attribute points to the `Servlet` you just wrote.

The `Servlet` should read the image for one product at a time, so the query would be slightly different: it should be enough to have

```
String sql = "SELECT pic FROM products where pk = " + pk;
```

Note that you need to specify this `pk` variable using some request parameter. The above line of code is just an example to demonstrate the idea. It is **very unsafe** to literally copy a request URL into an SQL query. Google for "SQL Injection" to read more about that.

Using [`Blob.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#getBinaryStream%28%29) you can obtain an `InputStream` whose contents you could copy to `response.getOutputStream()` in order to write it back to the browser. Don't forget to set the appropriate `content-type` on that response, for example "image/jpg" in case of JPEG pictures.

Comment: can you be more specific what the new servlet must have inside?

Comment: @marios: Just have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848819/how-to-display-image-from-database-in-servlet

and here also:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315671/how-to-retrieve-image-from-database-and-display-in-jsp-via-servlet

As I think its a better approach to store files in a directory and to keep directory path in DB.

Comment: Well, you **could** put the code in a JSP as well (like you're already fetching products from the database by calling the bean from your JSP), but I would advice against that approach because it violates the Model-View-Controller separation, IMHO.

Comment: is not mvc model is multy-tier model.

Comment: what if make some class in my accessor like getimg() and inside put it in? (instead of blob can i use something else more esay?)

Comment: That would not work, since you cannot include an image directly in your JSP. You will *always* need an `<img>` tag to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

As mthmulders said what you are seeing is the the value of Blob.toString().

BalusC posted sometime ago a 2 great articles on serving images recovered from a database blob through a servlet :

http://balusc.blogspot.fr/2007/04/imageservlet.html

And a more recent one with GZIP and resume handling

http://balusc.blogspot.fr/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html

Comment: Note that these examples read the images from a specified location on the filesystem, whereas the question is about images being stored in a relational database.

Comment: No actually the first link shows both, first from the filesystem then from a relational database

Comment: Marios regarding your comment "i am not working with servlet.i am working with classes" I agree with mthmulders you could put your code directly in the JSP but is not a good practice. By creating a separate servlet that handles the image you keep the view clean