# how to retrive image and display it on div from database

Tags: java, sql, email, blob

I am new to the blob data conversion of content. I am reading the emails and saving into database with body type as **BLOB**, if we have image embed into email even those are saving into it. but the problem is retrieving back and showing it to users. The image re-creation is not happening it says image path failed.

the src in image tag would be something like this.

```
cid:image001.png@01CF630F.005FA080
```

Please help with the suitable java code which 'll form image back and we can show into the division .

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also refers to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833184/java-blob-image-display

Answer (score 1):

I have solved same problem, by making a sevlet that returns the byte[] of the image. And call this servlet within the img src tag.

Example :
**This method will give you byte[] for any file, and method is in Utilities class**

```
public static byte[] getFileData ( String fileName ){
    File f = new File(fileName);
    byte data [] = new byte[ (int) f.length() ];

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        fis.read(data);
        fis.close();
        return data;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}**
```

and I have called this method from doGet of the servlet as following:

```
final String imageName = request.getParameter("imageName");    
byte[] imageData = Utilities.getFileData( ROOT_DIR + imageName );
response.getOutputStream().write(imageData);
```

In above code ROOT_DIR is also defined as **C:\Temp\FormData\Images\**

**My div is like this:**

```
<div>
<img src='http://localhost:9080/LoadImage?imageName=one.png' />
</div>
```

Comment: I ve read email completely and saved it into data base it's complete html structure which is stored nothing like path and all.. how to convert it back with correct format which 'll display image

Comment: Can your email has morethan one image?

Comment: may be it's user depended and images are inline i mean not attached

Comment: Show me the table structure, where you have stored this images. I have idea which will work if your mail contains only one image

Comment: i am just converting the data which 'll be a html structure into a blob(bytes) and stored into DB, n since the image is also converted and saved i dont know how to reform it back, but the email content is diplayed properly , the src prepared is something like this. <img width="130" height="54" alt="Description: colEnterprise" src="cid:image001.png@01CF630F.005FA080" id="Picture_x0020_1">

Comment: Meaning that your complete html is converted to blob and stored in db, am I understand it correctly?

Comment: yeah exactly the complete thing, not image in separate and content else where .

Comment: I have searched it and found this query "select  CAST(html AS CHAR) htmllayout from formlist where id = ?". Here htmllayout is in BLOB format